# Is it possible to specify that a string should match an interface property name in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, interface

I have an interface like this for example:

```js
interface Account {
    email: string;
    enabled: boolean;
}
```

And I would like to create a method that returns a default value for these fields. So I have something like this:

```js
function defaultValue(propName:string) {
    if (propName === 'email') return '';
    if (propName === 'enabled') return true;
}
```

It works well however if any property of `Account` changes, the `defautValue()` method would still compile even though it's now broken.

So I'm wondering if I can specify that `propName` should have a type like `property name of Account`? Or is there any other good pattern I can use to enforce type checking in that situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function to assert the variable is never by the end of the if statements and `keyof T` to get a union of keys:

```
function assertNever(v: never): never {
  throw new Error("Should never happen!");
}

function defaultValue(propName:keyof Account) {
    if (propName === 'email') return '';
    if (propName === 'enabled') return true;
    assertNever(propName);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIIQewK7mQbwFgAoZM5CAWzmABsAuZAZzClAHMBuE8ikOAEa0IAE0YDMmYXBDdiAXxIxcCMMEwhkcJk2hgAchABu0ABRHGIY9ACUl61AI9kYABZRMAd2RXvAUSgPKFMAIgBlVxxaER8HZFc4AAdEiBAAQhCbOUViJRU1DWQRCHhsWjAANThabAhTRI9E-ThKCHoAawgAT0wYNAwccBsnUnJgPvrG5tbkAF555AByKhpaReGoCDBsKE1FxbleceRJzCaWlHnZpdTBYRF15E3t3ZcoWsPybV0oAwdT86tLIkeRAA)

You can also improve the caller experience by making the function generic, but this will mean some type assertions in the implementation.

```
function defaultValue<K extends keyof Account>(propName:K): Account[K] {
    if (propName === 'email') return '' as Account[K];
    if (propName === 'enabled') return true as Account[K];
    assertNever(propName);
}

let email = defaultValue('email') // string
let enabled = defaultValue('enabled') // boolean
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIIQewK7mQbwFgAoZM5CAWzmABsAuZAZzClAHMBuE8ikOAEa0IAE0YDMmYXBDdiAXxIxcCMMEwhkcJk2hgAchABu0ABRHGIY9ACUl61AI9kYABZRMAd2RXvAUSgPKFMAIgBlVxxaER8HZFc4AAdEiBAAQhCbOUViEiUVNQ1kEQh4bFowADU4WmwIAB4AaQoAD0gQESZkAGsIAE9MGDQMHHAAPlNEj0T9OEoIeka7YaxcMABtRoBdJ1JyYCHJ6dn55ABeC+QAcioaWiubZCgIMGwoTSurrS70VfBNrZyXgHZBHTAzOYoC5na6pQTCEQPJ4vN6aVh1b4rUYbbZA8jaXRQAwOMEQ+ZZEg5EjCMAUah0c7FUpwcpVGp1Uw3en3R4Ael5zFYHGpLz48NEjJKZQq1VqEE5cKEoiR-OQEikEBkQA)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a more specific string type to the `propName` parameter. Then, use a switch statement to have smart type inference that you are correctly returning a value that matches the return type for each possible branch in the function.

```
interface Account {
    email: string;
    enabled: boolean;
    shouldError: boolean;
}

function defaultValue(propName: keyof Account): Account[keyof Account] { // shows error for not always returning value
    switch (propName) {
        case "email":
            return "";
        case "enabled":
            return true;
        // uncomment this code to fix the error
        // case "shouldError":
        //     return true;
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIIQewK7mQbwFgAoZM5CAWzmABsAuZAZzClAHMBuE8ikOAEa0IAE0YDMmYXBDdS5JgAsctEQFEoUTFHGTpskgF8SJGLgRhgmEMhER42WmABqcWtggAKAA5bvAOThKCEYAawgAT0wYNAwccABKRnQsXDAAbXComJT4sABdAmQAemLmZQB3JgpNbWQYOpBMMGQ3CrgI6qgIMGwoEA5kADc3Dx4FCuAwBEVkHz9A4ISCcd4yBDgmFAAiKhpabfpVtd5u3v7kbe25E-XNnYh+IVFD49vkM76bVg8b29LkOZMJRgngwIpgNUsHZkGBMPVgAAPWGKFDQLRQN7kAEbLaXJQqdS1KCveQnAGnHpfWFQX7HYzEQxAA)